# Fail to install drush via pear

Tags: drush

I try to install drush using the following command:

```
pear install drush/drush
```

I get this error message:

> No releases available for package "pear.drush.org/drush" install failed.

Then I try with `sudo`:

```
sudo install drush/drush
```

I get this error message:

> downloading drush-5.4.0.tgz …
> Starting to download drush-5.4.0.tgz (398,652 bytes) done: 398,652 bytes
> Could not rename /usr/bin/.tmpdrush to /usr/bin/drush copy(/usr/bin/drush): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
> ERROR: commit failed.

I installed pear, and added the pear.drush.org channel. What is wrong?

---

I realize that my question was not very clear. I was trying  to install drush using pear on OSX Mountain Lion and I got those errors. Anyway I managed to accomplish my task another way, by installing ["homebrew"](https://brew.sh) package manager and following a few steps from [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20151018094006/http://www.alexweber.com.br/en/articles/mac-development-replacing-mamp-11-easy-steps) tutorial (step 8 and 9).

Update: an even simpler way to install drush using [homebrew](https://brew.sh):

```
brew install drush
```

That's it.

Answer (score 5):

Use the following commands:

```bsh
sudo rm /usr/bin/drush
sudo pear install drush/drush
sudo drush --version
```

Comment: or if you previously installed drush in /usr/local/bin, then use: sudo rm /usr/local/bin/drush

Comment: Just for the record, since this question suddenly was listed as active again: Drush hasn't supported installation through Pear for many years. Read https://www.drush.org/latest/install/ for current install instructions which requires the use of Composer.